# Liquibase is trying to create the same table twice

Tags: liquibase

I'm new to liquibase and I'm trying to run some test(version 3.6.3).

1. I created an empty database named 'liquibase_testing'
2. I created a migrations.xml file that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
        <includeAll path="migrations" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

3. I created a simple CREATE TABLE script and saved in in the `migrations` directory as `001-liquibase-testing-create-names-table.sql`. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.names (
name_id int identity,
first_name nvarchar(100),
last_name nvarchar(100),
primary key clustered (name_id)
)
```

4. I ran the liquibase migration with cli like this:

```
    ./_liquibase/liquibase-3.6.3-bin/liquibase 
    --driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
    --classpath=./_jdbc/sqljdbc_7.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.2.0.jre8.jar      
    --changeLogFile=./liquibase_testing/resources/migrations.xml 
    --url="jdbc:sqlserver://myDbServer;database=liquibase_testing"      
    --username=liquibase_testing      
    --password=password     
    --logLevel=debug      
    migrate
```

And I get this error:

```
    Starting Liquibase at Thu, 14 Feb 2019 12:54:52 EST (version 3.6.3 built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48)
    Unexpected error running Liquibase: There is already an object named 'names' in the database. [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE dbo.names (
    name_id int identity,
    first_name nvarchar(100),
    last_name nvarchar(100),
    primary key clustered (name_id)
    )]
    liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase_testing/resources/migrations/001-liquibase-testing-create-names-table.sql::raw::includeAll:
         Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: There is already an object named 'names' in the database. [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE dbo.names (
    name_id int identity,
    first_name nvarchar(100),
    last_name nvarchar(100),
    primary key clustered (name_id)
    )]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:637)
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1220)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:199)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:137)
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: There is already an object named 'names' in the database. [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE dbo.names (
    name_id int identity,
    first_name nvarchar(100),
    last_name nvarchar(100),
    primary key clustered (name_id)
    )]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:356)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:57)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:125)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1229)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1211)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:600)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'names' in the database.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:256)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1621)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:868)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:768)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2930)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:744)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:352)
        ... 12 common frames omitted


    For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

So the `names` table gets created but then for some reason Liquibase tries to create it a second time and fails. I ran a profiler trace on the database and can see 2 `CREATE TABLE` calls.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still have this problem... I would look into the database table DATABASECHANGELOG to see if the creation of that table is known to liquibase.

If not, you could either drop the table, or find out how do you inform liquibase that this changeset has already been applied (I am a liquibase beginner too... but it looks like the command line option "generateChangeLog" might be what you need...)

Answer (score 0):

Just the same issue with Liquibase 3.2.0 + PostgreSQL.

**!!! UPD:** It's all ok with Liquibase & PostgreSQL.
It was Hibernate trying to create the table too, because of its ddl-auto setting. That's why CREATE TABLE was executed twice.